# How to do id duplicate checking in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

```
      for(int i =1; i< Member.count-1; i++) {                         
           if(members[i]==null) {                        
            members[i] = new Member(id, pwd);    
            pw.print("welcome");


            break;
           }
           else if(!members[i].getId().equals(id)) {          
            pw.print("join clear!");   
           }

           else {
            pw.print("already id exist.");

            break;
           }


         }
     }


    pw.println("</body></html>");
```

I want to do id duplicate checking. 
I tried it however I didn't get success.

Comment: Not sure if other members would be able to understand your problem statement in one go. I would request you to review your problem statement and be specific to your problem and share what issue you are facing.

Comment: Can you show your inputs and outputs with some logical explanation.?